# The action can't be completed because the file is open in Java Platform SE Binary?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have written an runnable JAR file for a simple barcode generator application. When I export it from eclipse to my desktop, run it and then decide to delete it, it pops up with: [image: Error in deleting]

What can I write in my source code that would prevent this? A way of killing of any threads that may be lingering? Or any sessions held in the JVM?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: You get the same error if you try and delete a file open in Notepad.

Comment: Yes, however, with norepad, you can close notepad and if you try and delete, it will not say that. My code is not terminating the runnable jar, which is what is required.

Comment: Then I suggest you **post your code**.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of execution or before terminating the main thread, I prefer using `System.exit(STATUS_CODE)` where we git rid of any file being used by current process or instance run

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out, I never had a "System.exit(0);" called in my code. So I used:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

This internally uses "System.exit();", whereby when you press the "x" button on the Java application window, it will exit all running threads of Java in the JVM. Then terminating the JVM itself. Please be aware, if you have any other Java threads open, EXIT_ON_CLOSE will close all of them. After closing all the Java SE Binary executables running in the JVM via Task Manager, I added this to my code and outputted a new runnable JAR. I ran it, then closed it and then went off to delete it. It deleted successfully.

I hope this helps anyone that may be stuck on this.